# putting in a separator between posts in loop

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have the following loop which brings in the title of each post onto my page

html

```
<?php 
if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post(); 
        echo '<div class="cell"><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></div>';
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
```

css

```
.cell {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

I want to put a separator between each title/link brought in (not on the ends)

example output

```
link  <div class="separate"></div>  
link  <div class="separate"></div>  link
```

Comment: Can't you use ```<br>```?

Comment: I want to put a custom separator while keeping them aligned ( i realize i forgot to add that part and will edit my post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple solution using additional flag variable `$first`

```
<?php 
    if ( have_posts() ) {
        $first = true;

        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post(); 

            if($first){
                $first = false;
            } else {
                // echo separator
            }

            echo '<div class="cell"><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></div>';
        } // end while
    } // end if
?>
```

Comment: having trouble echoing my separator literally just need a div called 'separator' to be in between the links

Comment: replace `// echo separator` with `echo '<div class="separator"></div>';`

Comment: my apologies I had a typo, your solution works great to, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could put in a `<hr>` element at the end of your echo like this:

```
echo '<div class="cell"><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></div><hr>';
```

Comment: will this solve the problem of separators at the ends?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a counter and compare the counter with **posts per page** to check if you have reached last post.

You can get **posts per page** from options table like this:

```
$default_posts_per_page = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
```

Check if you have reached the last post, then don't print out the separator.

```
$counter = 1;
while ( have_posts() ) {

    //your stuffs

    if ($counter != $default_posts_per_page) {
        //print separator
    }

    $counter++;
}
```